# Grease Pencil thickness inconsistency causing line boil/flickering/shimmering on camera move

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart, lines

I work only in grease pencil and have a possible anti-aliasing issue (I attempted to increase the grease pencil anti-aliasing past 1 to 10 to 100, while it looks different than 0 it is pointless past 1).

**(edit as links were requested to be removed)**
it is as though a thickness noise modifier has been applied but only when the camera moves.

I had a similar line boil but less drastic issue in 2.93.0 and 2.93.14  I labeled the different render settings, image sequences tend to do slightly better than video.  I did renders from blender at it's factory default as well as my normal default,it looked the same.

I wish to know if there is a current work around for the flickering lines.  the go to in 2.8 was render at 200% and shrink it which diminished it some.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Are there stroke settings that can cause this?  Are there Camera settings? is there another area in render settings other than grease pencil anti-aliasing that can affect line quality? is there more than one area where you have to change anti-aliasing settings?

I have looked up this issue and have found other people who mostly just use grease pencil who have run into this problem and they were either using a very old version or they went unanswered. this was practically nonexistent as a problem for me in 2.79b (possibly 2.80).

I have windows 10 with 16 gigs of memory
nvidia GeForce GTX 970 with most recent drivers.

some friends rendered on theirs to see if it happened to them.
-linux 2.93.
-similar windows 10 3.1.2 same.

all answers I found seem to imply that this is a problem only in pre 2.9 but here it is.

**List of solutions for other's looking, like me, and finding nothing about settings**

Render at 200%-300% and shrink it back down in a composition program that doesn't have this problem.  it's still present but diminished.

use thick lines.  Stylistically limited

Boil the animation on purpose. Stylistically limited.

Add style filters in a composition program that doesn't have this problem.  Such as recreating a CRT television.  Stylistically limited.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

That flickering is driving me nuts as well. Besides the solution you mentioned there is one more that in my opinion gives best results. Instead of using solid materials for strokes you can use textured one. If the texture  has soft edges it would create kind of a fake anti aliasing which reduces the flickering. It will still boil when the lines would be too thin or would be too close to each other but the flickering would be significantly reduced